# How to check if ObjectResult collection was empty?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable, nullable, executestorequery

I have this piece of code which check the last customer_id from the db.

```
ObjectResult<int?> last_customer_id_collection = MainForm.eggsContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int?>("select MAX(customer_id) from customers");
```

Then I get the next id required like this

```
new_customer_id = last_customer_id_collection.FirstOrDefault<int?>().Value + 1;
```

It's working, HOWEVER when dealing with a new empty db the statment `last_customer_id_collection.FirstOrDefault<int?>()` throws an InvalidOperationException.

How can I check if last_customer_id_collection was empty without try catch?

(p.s. I was trying to check if `last_customer_id_collection.Any<int?>()` or `last_customer_id_collection.Count<int?>()` or DefaultIfEmpty etc. but everything I try causes this exception)

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: Why are you including `<int?>`?  Is the collection actually of type `int?` or `int` or something else?  I suspect this could be the root of your problem.

Comment: Could you post the Stacktrace and/or the exception message? So we could see whats going on here exactly. It may be that your database connection is causing the ``InvalidOperationException`` because the actual call to the database gets deferred until you call ``FirstOrDefault``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an InvalidOperationException because `Nullable<T>.HasValue` would return false.

You will need to modify the code to not call `.Value` if the query return value is null.

```
var custId = last_customer_id_collection.FirstOrDefault<int?>();
if(custId.HasValue)
    DoStuffWithId();
else
    DoStuffWithNullResult();
```

Small Example that demonstrates the potentialy confusing behaviors of Nullables
This will print:

"Null!", "No Value but no NullReferenceException" and then "Oops, InvalidOperationException"

```
List<int?> values = new List<int?>();

var test = values.FirstOrDefault();

if (test == null)
    Console.WriteLine("Null!");

if (test.HasValue)
    Console.WriteLine(test.Value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("No Value but no NullReferenceException");

try
{
    int value = test.Value;
}
catch(InvalidOperationException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Oops, InvalidOperationException");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference between your answer an Michaels? This is does not seem to be the problem here, as it would throw a NullReferenceException, not an InvalidOperationException. Edit: Michael just deleted his answer...

Comment: No it would not throw a NullReferenceException because he's using int?

Comment: Your right, just checked it: ``(new int?[] { null, 2, 3 }).FirstOrDefault().Value;`` throws an ``InvalidOperationException`` indeed. Didnt know that. +1 for you :)

Comment: added a small example that demonstrates how you can get the InvalidOperationException but no NullReferenceException, and how you can call HasValue on a variable that test true to a null check.

Comment: You're a genius. But I still can't understand why when debugging and trying to evaluate last_customer_id_collection.FirstOrDefault<int?>() from the watch window it gives the InvalidOpertationException, but from the code `var custId = last_customer_id_collection.FirstOrDefault<int?>()` it doesn't throw that exception??